# Javascript executing incorrectly on Apache Cordova index.js/.html

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio, cordova

So in an application I'm writing using Apache Cordova within Visual Studio, I am attempting to add functionality to the default index.html and index.js.  However, my code within my index.js is executing very oddly - the debugger in VS shows that the $('#favorite-lot') is executed, but nothing within the .click(function()) method is.  Is there any reason why this would be so?

Index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/JQueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/JQueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

            <div role="main" class="ui-content">
                <a id="favorite-lot" href=""><h5>Favorite Lot</h5></a>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Index.js

```
//This method is called on page load to set the favorite lot on the index page
//the document bit is called, but the if statement within it & ready aren't
//$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('#favorite-lot').click(function () {
        var storage = window.localStorage;
        var href = storage.getItem("favoriteLot");
        //now redirect
        window.location.replace(href); 
    }); 
//});
```

Note I have tried enclosing my function within a document.ready (see commented out code), however the results are the same.

EDIT: So I figured this issue out, and it was a fairly simple error: I wasn't including the jQuery code itself, just jQuery.mobile, and additionally, the jQuery has to load before jQuery.mobile for the .mobile stuff to work.  Side note, I also didn't realize .mobile enables Ajax on most links/redirections, and had to disable that for some of my other code; maybe if you've found this post, you're suffering from the other problem as well

Comment: You perform a **getItem** in localStorage... Where do you **set** the value prior to that? Beside this... Do you have any error in console ?

Comment: The item is set in another page - I have confirmed the item is set in local storage, however I did adjust my code to check for a null condition, and the issue remains.  There are no errors in my JavaScript console.  The file seems to simply skip over the code within the function() block.

Comment: So `console.log("href: "+href);` doesn't even trigger ?

Comment: If you have the href console logged... It think there could be something about `window.location.replace(...)`. Maybe `window.location.assign(...)` would be more appropriate.

Comment: @Steffan Try placing a simple alert inside click function to see if the function is invoked first.

Comment: @Gandhi I've tried that and the alert does not trigger.